# Ошибка при создании массива: can't assign to function call "owm = pyowm"

Tags: python

Добрый день при создании программного кода появилась ошибка: can't assign to function call (ошибка при создании массива). Версия Python 3.9. Пожалуйста, подскажите как её исправить.
Скриншот прилагаю.

Код:

```
owm = pyowm.OWM('1347502ad4321effc57919da4b5d792e'), Language = ("ru")
place = input("В каком городе/стране")
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скобку  уберите перед Language и перед ru

Comment: Добрый день,спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 0):

```
owm = pyowm.OWM('1347502ad4321effc57919da4b5d792e', language='ru')
```